# Shared preferences overwritten when app is closed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Hi my app is having an issue where the data in the shared preferencedata is overwritten when the app is reopened after a force close.

Here is my code where I initalise the app + my log calls

```
private String TAG = "MainActivity";
public int score;
public int highScore;
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "HighScore"; // This is shared preference name

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking highscore Value Oncreate:" + highScore);
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking score Value Oncreate:" + score);
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking Shared preference highscore Value Oncreate:" + data.getInt("HighScore", 0));
}
```

Here is my method where which includes the saving and calling fucntion of the shared preference.

```
 public void generateH(View v){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coinResult);

    if (number == 1){
        myText.setText("HEADS");
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        score = score+1;
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);

        if(highScore > score)
        {
            // This will store the new high score in the sharedpreferences.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("HighScore", highScore);
            editor.apply(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background

        }
        else
        {
            highScore = score;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("HighScore", score);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    else{
        myText.setText("TAILS");

        AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
        myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is: " +  data.getInt("HighScore", 0) )
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();

        score = 0;
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);

        if(highScore > score)
        {
            // This will store the new high score in the sharedpreferences.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("HighScore", highScore);
            editor.apply(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background
            // after this highscore will be 100
        }
        else
        {
            highScore = score;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("HighScore", score);
            editor.apply();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking highscore Value genHLoseCondition:" + highScore);
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking score Value genHLoseCondition::" + score);
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking Shared preference highscore Value genHLoseCondition::" + data.getInt("HighScore", 0));
        myAlert.show();
    }

}
```

Here are my logs:

> 01-07 12:16:13.602    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking highscore Value Oncreate:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:13.602    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking score Value Oncreate:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:13.603    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking Shared preference highscore Value Oncreate:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:23.947    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking highscore Value genHLoseCondition:2
>
> 01-07 12:16:23.947    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking score Value genHLoseCondition::0
>
> 01-07 12:16:23.948    3189-3189/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking Shared preference highscore Value genHLoseCondition::2
>
> 01-07 12:16:46.446    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking highscore Value Oncreate:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:46.446    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking score Value Oncreate:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:46.460    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking Shared preference highscore Value Oncreate:2
>
> 01-07 12:16:48.624    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking highscore Value genHLoseCondition:0
>
> 01-07 12:16:48.624    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking score Value genHLoseCondition::0
>
> 01-07 12:16:48.624    3218-3218/? D/MainActivity﹕ Checking Shared preference highscore Value genHLoseCondition::0

as can be seen the shared preference value is remembered onCreate but the moment a new value is created it is passed into the shared preference. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition where you compare high score, the value in high score variable is 0 as you are not assigning shared preference value to that variable .

Comment: So it should be something at the start like highscore = sharedprefence("highscore", 0);. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes first get the stored value in the variable and then compare it